# Mac OSX Launchd launches process 3 hours early

Tags: macos, cron, launchd

I have setup launchd to launch at 7:30am but the event fires at 4:30am.  I am EST, I am assuming it thinks PST (since Apple is in PST).  I have rebooted, checked the date/time config, time zone, etc.  No luck in my searches in these forums or elsewhere.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.myname.ip_mailer</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/Users/myname/Bin/ip_mailer.py</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>30</integer>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Wanna show us your `plist` file?

Comment: Added plist to original post.

Comment: Oh, and just a note, the 10:30am is in there so I get it at 7:30am.  If I put 7:30am like I originally had, I get it at 4:30am.

Comment: Mmmm... http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-101707.html

Comment: So, what happens if you run `date` in Terminal? And what happens if you run `sudo systemsetup gettimezone`

Comment: With date, I get the correct time (currently 1:43pm Sep 8 EDT 2014.  With gettimezone I received America/New York

Comment: MArk, on the hintsforum, I have rebooted multiple times and also even removed the job from launchctl and re-added it.  Note, this machine has been in EST since I bought it (except for possibly the first few minutes during initial setup where who knows what it was, probably PST).

Comment: It turns out it was hotmail showing the time of the email incorrectly.  I added a time stamp to the email subject and it was being processed at the correct time.  Good old Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was hotmail showing the time of the email incorrectly. I added a time stamp to the email subject and it was being processed at the correct time. Good old Microsoft...